# ActiveMQ c++ tutorial

Tags: c++, jms

Can anyone recommend a good tutorial on JMS with c++ and ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The examples that ship with the library are also pretty good. They have simple, straightforward examples like a simple async consumer and a simple producer which work together.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/activemq-cpp/trunk/activemq-cpp/src/examples/

Answer (score 3):

To use C++ and JMS together:

http://www.codemesh.com/products/junction/examples/jms.html
http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=28570

Well, For ActiveMQ:

http://docs.1060.org/docs/3.3.0/book/tutorial/doc_tutorial_jms.html
http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html

and for JMS itself:
http://java.sun.com/products/jms/tutorial/